# EcorResCategory get childrens x++

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, x++, dynamics-365

I need to get all childrens (and its childrens) for a parent product category

example:

```
Parent
-- child 1
-- child 2
---- child 2.1
---- child 2.2
-- child 3
```

I am using the `EcoResCategory.getChildren()` method but it gets the first children only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"but it gets the first children only"

I don't think that is correct. If you take a look at the references of the `EcoResCategory.getChildren()` method, there is method `WarrantyLookupProcessingJob.updateLookupCategory()` that shows the following pattern:

```cs
EcoResCategory childCategory = parentCategory.getChildren();
while (childCategory)
{
    next childCategory;
}
```

The `next` keyword retrieves the next record from the `childCategory` table buffer. See also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/fin-ops-core/dev-itpro/dev-ref/xpp-data/xpp-select

Also note that the `getChildren` method has a `_levelLimit` parameter with the following documentation:
`An <c>EcoResCategoryLevel</c> value that indicates the maximum level of children categories to retrieve.`

Comment: thanks! I didn't know the next keyword